# Error 505 Deploy 500.Blueimp file upload

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, deployment, blueimp

When I publish my application, I receive an `HTTP 500` error - but when I run it on *localhost* it works normally. I am trying to use a `text/plain` content type for the return, but I have also have done tests with `content/json`.

I'm not sure what I'm missing - maybe I'm wrong somewhere. Here is my code:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/upload/jquery.ui.widget.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/upload/jquery.iframe-transport.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/upload/jquery.fileupload.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {

        $('#fileupload').fileupload({

            dataType: 'json',
            url: '@Url.Action("cargarExcel", "Home")',
            formData: { example: '123456789876' },
            done: function (e, DataTotal) {

                $("#RespuestaCarga").append('<table id="tablaDatos"></table>')
                $("#tablaDatos").append('<th>Comentario</th><th>Cantidad</th>');

                for (var i = 0; i < DataTotal.result.olistaTabla.length; i++) {
                    comentario = DataTotal.result.olistaTabla[i].comentario;
                    cantidad = DataTotal.result.olistaTabla[i].cantidad;

                    $("#tablaDatos").append('<tr><td>' + comentario + '</td><td>' + cantidad + '</td>');
                }
            },
            add: function (e, data) {
                $("#btnsend").off('click').on('click', function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    data.submit();
                });
            }
        });

    });
</script>

<input id="fileupload" type="file" name="files" multiple="multiple"/>
<label id="namefile"></label>
<input id="btnsend" type="submit" value="Enviar" />
<div id="RespuestaCarga"></div>
```

My Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult cargarExcel(HttpPostedFileBase files, string example)
{
    using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(oSqlConnIN))
    {
        bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "tb_RutasMasivo_planning";
        bulkCopy.WriteToServer(data);
    }

    Conexion cn = new Conexion();

    DataSet dsRespuesta = new DataSet();
    dsRespuesta = cn.ejecutarDataSet("storedprocedure", example, Personid);

    dtresumen = dsRespuesta.Tables[0];
    dtDataRutas = dsRespuesta.Tables[1];

    mensaje = Util.GetJSONString(dtresumen);

    ds.Tables.Clear();

    Tabla_request tabla;
    tabla = HelperJson.Deserialize<Tabla_request>(mensaje);

    return Json(tabla,"text/plain");
}
```

My problem is that when I test localhost works fine, but when I compile and publish the project returns me error 500. It seems that the problem is due to the return type.
The response that the server sends

[image]
[image]

Now the image, with the published project[image]

Comment: We would be able to help you much more effectively if you provided a [short, self-contained, correct example](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: I posted my problem with images. Sorry for my bad English. thanks

Comment: can u set customerrors off and post what specific error message is being returned along with 500 internal error

Comment: Now the image, with the published project.set customerrors off. Thanks

Comment: Localhost response header content-type: application/json. And server response header content-type:text/html, Is that the problem?